# Keep instances tree when object are deserialized

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Dealing with this java serializable class,

```
public class MyTree implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3857878156205663235L;
    public MyTree parent;
    public String name;

    public MyTree() {
        parent = null;
        name = "root";
    }

    public MyTree(MyTree p, String n) {
        parent = p;
        name = n;
    }
}
```

I instantiate several MyTree before (de)serializing the objects :

```
//                root
//                  |
//                branch_1
//                 /    \
//         branch_1_1   branch_1_2


    private static void mytree() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        MyTree root = new MyTree();

        MyTree branch_1 = new MyTree(root, "branch_1");
        MyTree branch_1_1 = new MyTree(branch_1, "branch_1_1");
        MyTree branch_1_2 = new MyTree(branch_1, "branch_1_2");

        System.out.println("parent branch 1_1 : " + branch_1_1.parent);
        System.out.println("parent branch 1_2 : " + branch_1_2.parent);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Serialization");
        System.out.println();
        MyTree new_branch_1_1 = serializeAndDeserialize(branch_1_1);
        MyTree new_branch_1_2 = serializeAndDeserialize(branch_1_2);

        System.out.println("parent branch 1_1 : " + new_branch_1_1.parent);
        System.out.println("parent branch 1_2 : " + new_branch_1_2.parent);
    }

    public static <T> T serializeAndDeserialize(T o) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            // serialize the Object
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            so.writeObject(o);

            // deserialize the Object
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream si = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            return (T)si.readObject();
    }
```

After the deserialization of branch_1_1 branch_1_2, I observe that the relation is lost and two new instances of MyTree corresponding to branch_1 and root are created.

In reality those objects will be deserialized inside an other JVM.
How can i keep the relation between the objects if a client sends two objects in relation (like branch_1_1 and branch_1_2) ?

If the client sends a 'linear' tree the (de)serialization as performed in this short example is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After the deserialization of branch_1_1 branch_1_2, I observe that the relation is lost and two new instances of MyTree corresponding to branch_1 and root are created.

That is what happens when you take a copy of those objects.  They have no relationship to the original objects.

> How can i keep the relation between the objects if a client sends two objects in relation (like branch_1_1 and branch_1_2) ?

Don't send the branches by themselves if you don't want their copies to end up as independent objects.

You should serialize the whole tree and then all the relationships will be preserved because you are copying the whole tree.

```
MyTree new_root = serializeAndDeserialize(root);
```

Now you have a copy of the `root` tree with all the relationships.